# Limesurvey offline UI support

Tags: limesurvey

I want to create a survey using limesurvey and export it as UI (HTML/JS/CSS) for offline usage.

I want these pages to be exported and then used as offline html application(file://) for mobile using webview without need of internet.

As far as response is there, I can capture this response at javascript level and cache it (localstorage) and when network is available, I may submit it.

I tried searching if there is any possibility of offline support from limesurvey but I did not get anything.

Can someone please provide any pointers? I am not a PHP developer so if you think that after doing some changes in PHP code, thats possible, then please suggest where should I look for?

Comment: hm, if i understood correctly this means you have to store files on your mobile, in html, css and php, im not sure mobiles can handle such things locally on their drive? You could however install and access a offline version of limesurvey on any computer..

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can keep the survey on a single page, you can save the generated survey in an html file which contains all the javascript Limesurvey creates for that survey.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the mentioned approach is that even if you succeed in storing all HTML + JS + CSS of the whole survey, it will not look very nice when running such a "fake survey" on your local device. You'll have to scroll a lot and most probably the download HTML + CSS doesn't contain any optimization for mobile devices.

Furthermore, if you store data locally by adding some additional JS, you need to make sure to store it in a proper format to be able to upload responses back to Limesurvey.

I have recently tested a Limesurvey Android app called "OfflineSurveys" (see [offlinesurveys.com](http://offlinesurveys.com/)) and they seem to have solved those issues. I was even able to run a survey in Limesurvey's group by group and question by question mode.

According to http://www.offlinesurveys.com/sync-responses-automatically the app can even sync responses automatically at the background once Internet connection is available.